# Stripe Create Invoice and auto charge

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am creating an invoice and auto charging a customer via their PHP package. The issue is though the invoice is created but the card on file is not charged, it says fail. This is odd to me because if I go into the dashboard online, find the invoice the is listed as "failed" and manually click the "retry charge" it works. Why would this be? Its clearly creating the invoice correctly and trying to charge the card on file but the card seems to only clear on ALL of these invoices if I go in and manually retry the charge.

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(config('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'));

$item = $stripe->invoiceItems->create([
    'customer' => $subscription->stripe_customer,
    'amount' => $total,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'description' => 'Erro Coffee Subscription ' . $subscription_type->bags
 ]);

$invoice = $stripe->invoices->create([
     'customer' => $subscription->stripe_customer,
     'collection_method' => 'charge_automatically',
     'auto_advance' => true,
     "metadata" => [
            "order_type" => "subscription",
            "subscription_refill" => "true",
            "subscription_id" => $subscription->id
      ]
 ]);
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the failure?  What is the reason the payment failed?  How long did it take to fail?  If you [ask the API to attempt Invoice payment immediately](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/pay) after creating the Invoice does that also fail the first time?  If so can you provide the failure details provided by the API?

Comment: The code you show only shows creating the invoice, it doesn't show any payment capture or processing. Please update your code. Also you should really be looking at your client PHP code to see if there are errors in the PHP aspect, also which should be highlighted by the Stripe error feedback, which you should also be showing us to help you.

Comment: @Martin there is no payment capture since they have a card on file already in stripe as a customer. The `'collection_method' => 'charge_automatically', auto_advance' => true,` charges their card

Comment: @Packy then you capture the payment from a card on file. You need to show the code for Stripe being told to use a card on file.

Comment: @Martin this is the code. Per their docs I create an invoice and set it to 'charge_automatically' and thats it. Stripe then creates the invoice and auto charges the card on file


https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/automatic-charging

Comment: @Packy thank you. Are you able to give details about the failure notice; is it a testing card? If not, perhaps the customer card declined the request? This should be available in the Stripe card payment logs (from the Dashboard).

Comment: Probably a silly question but when you saved the card previously was it done with the parameter 'setup_future_usage' => 'off_session' ?

Comment: Have you made sure that the Customer has a default Payment Method set at `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` (see https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method)? Invoices with `collection_method: charge_automatically` can only be automatically charged if the Customer has a default PM.